# What would cause a url to resolve differently depending on whether I click it or copy/past into browser?

Tags: browser, url

I received an email from a client that had a link to their instagram page. When I Ctrl-clicked the link, it resolved to a page that is obviously not theirs, but which has their (rather unique) name in it. However when I copy/paste the link into my browser it resolves to the correct page.

On my colleague's computer Ctrl-clicking the link works just fine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the equivalent of `<a href="http://badsite">http://goodsite</a>` I.e the displayed link and possibly the one you are copying is goodsite and the one that the link goes to is actually badsite?

Comment: I wondered that at first, so I that's why I asked my colleague to try the link on his machine. He had been copied on the same email. He had no trouble clicking through to the correct site.